# How can I center a nav list in bootstrap 3 when it wraps

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, centering

I cant post an image, but i have a navigation menu on a site im coding. Im trying to crush the site for mobile, but when I do this the li menu drops under. However I want it to center.

This is the code i have so far

```
@media (min-width:768px){


}


<ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-menu img-centered">
     <li class="nav-link-green"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
     <li class="nav-link-yellow"><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
     <li class="nav-link-red"><a href="#">Parents & Carers</a></li>
     <li class="nav-link-blue"><a href="youngpeople.aspx">Young People</a></li>
     <li class="nav-link-purple"><a href="#">News & Updates</a></li>
     <li class="nav-link-green"><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
     <li class="nav-link-blue dropdown">
                <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" href="#">Publications <span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Safeguarding Library</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Learning Zone</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">TSCB Publications</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

I hope this makes sense. If you need anything more please let me know. This is my first post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, worked this out. Just added this code to the css.

```
ul {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  float: none;
}
```

This makes it happen.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the class .collapse on your nav?
like here: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar

Comment: Ive just inserted 'collapse' into this line

<ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-menu img-centered">

No luck. Everything is still sticking to the left